# Howe can I save more strings in cookie and place them in list?

Tags: javascript, cookies

mI have the next javascript code:

```
    function setCookie(cname,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie= cname+"; "+expires
}
function delCookie(cname) {
    document.cookie = cname + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
function change(cname) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("but");
    if (elem.style.backgroundColor=="pink") 
    {
        elem.style.backgroundColor="#ff5d6d";
        delCookie(cname);
    }
    else {
        elem.style.backgroundColor="pink";
        setCookie(cname);
    }
}
```

I have made few buttons to add a string by clicking it once and remove it by clicking it again. but it just saves 3 times after the 3 one he replace the string with the old one. I want to save more strings in a cookie. and when i write document.writeln(document.cookie) i want to place the strings between each other. Iam making a favorite buttun that save the string and add it to another page.

Comment: what you are saying makes no sense "i dont want them next to each other but between each other". please try to explain

Comment: I have made few buttons to add a string by clicking it once and remove it by clicking it again. but it just saves 3 times after the 3 one he replace the string with the old one. I want to save more strings in a cookie. and when i write document.writeln(document.cookie) i want to place the strings between each other.

Comment: sounds like you will have to create a scheme for your cookie variable. like stringA|stringB|stringC

Comment: Something like that:)
but i want to place them bunder A and C under B
and i want to save more strings than 3.